# Printing pdf on mobile using wired printer connected to the computer, batch file, and a dropbox

Tags: batch-file, printing

I am using batch file to send uploaded pdf document from my mobile to usb printer using dropbox folder. I use free PDFtoPrinter program to print  and scheduled task to periodically run a batch file. The batch file contains following code.

```
"C:\Dropbox\PDFtoPrinter" "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf"

move "c:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf" "C:\Dropbox\printed"
```

The script function well if sent files folder contains pdf file but if it is empty, it gets stuck.
I would like to use if statement to check if folder contains pdf file. The script should exist if none is found. I am not a programmer. Kindly help

```
"C:\Dropbox\PDFtoPrinter" "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf"

move "c:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.*" "C:\Dropbox\printed"
```

Problem : if sent file folder is empty, the script gets stuck. Scheduled task next time does not work

Comment: C:\Dropbox\PDFtoPrinter. exe

Comment: `if exist "c:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf" ...`

Comment: I would do it the opposite way, add a new first line, ```@If Not Exist "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf" Exit 1```.

Comment: What is the difference between Stephan Vs your @Compo solution.

Comment: Stephan: "if a file exists, do something" vs. Compo: "if no file exists, do nothing".  It's pretty much the same result. Which one is better, mainly depends on your overall-logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my comments put together as a batch file.

```bash
@If Not Exist "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf" Exit 1
"C:\Dropbox\PDFtoPrinter.exe" "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf"
If Not ErrorLevel 1 Move /Y "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf" "C:\Dropbox\printed"
```

Alternatively, using the `for` loop method, you should be able to forego the `If` with `Exist` command.

```bash
@For %%G In ("C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf") Do @(
    "C:\Dropbox\PDFtoPrinter.exe" "%%G"
    If Not ErrorLevel 1 Move /Y "%%G" "C:\Dropbox\printed"
)
```

If there are no PDF files, then nothing will pass to the `Do` portion, and your PDFtoPrinter command will not be invoked, and nothing eill be stuck.

Answer (score 1):

```
if exist "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf" "C:\Dropbox\PDFtoPrinter" "C:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.pdf"

move "c:\Dropbox\Sent files\*.*" "C:\Dropbox\printed" 2>nul
```

The `if exist` will only execute the `pdftoprinter` executable if there are `.pdf` files present in the directory.

The `2>nul` will suppress error messages should there be no files in `sent files`

ALthough - perhaps the `move` should use a filemask of `*.pdf` (all `.pdf` files) in place of `*.*` (all files)

Comment: It may be better to use an ErrorLevel or conditional returned from PDFtoPrinter.exe before just moving all of the files. However, if multiple PDF files exist in the source directory, and one fails, nothing will be moved. For that reason, I'd advise a `For` loop.

Comment: Will you please provide me with a code. It is nice small utility which makes printing from mobile simple task. I used many shared wifi based utilities with multiple failures. Kindly help me create this simple solution

Comment: The two lines I've posted *is* a solution.